# Open a file from the desktop in a single window (without home screen splitscreen)

Tags: window

When I open a file from the context menu by choosing "Open with Emacs", Emacs starts with a horizontal splitscreen. The first window shows the desired file and the other one the home screen.

Is it possible to change the behaviour of emacs so that only the file is opened without the home screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by home screen you mean this screen

> [[image]]

just check the "Never show it again." checkbox and click on the "Dismiss this startup screen" button.  Or you can set the `inhibit-startup-screen` variable to t by customizing it (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `inhibit-startup-screen` <kbd>RET</kbd>) or adding

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
```

to your init file.