# Is it possible to disable the startup screen only when emacs opens a file?

Tags: start-up

Whenever I issue `$ emacs`, I am greeted by the startup screen. I like this.

However, when I issue `$ emacs foo.txt`, `emacs` opens `foo.txt` and the startup screen in a split screen. I do not like this.

Is it possible to disable the startup screen only when `emacs` is used to open a file?

I am not asking whether or not I can disable the startup screen (this is addressed [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7154/open-a-file-from-the-desktop-in-a-single-window-without-home-screen-splitscreen))

Comment: The problem with trying to fiddle with `startup.el` is that the code is baked into the Emacs executable.  It *may* be possible to catch a function in the startup process and redefine it, but it may also *not* be possible.  This is why I build my own Emacs and have my own `startup.el` so that I can control exactly how and when things happen when starting Emacs.  It would be easier to just close the Welcome window after calling `emacs foo.txt` with the `after-init-hook` or the `emacs-startup-hook`, or putting the `delete-other-windows` at the tail end of the `.emacs` file.

Comment: I assumed this would be possible, since this is exactly how `$ emacs -nw foo.txt` behaves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach is to exploit the hooks `command-line-functions`, which are called with variable `argi` dynamically bound to any unrecognised command-line options. The following are some of the many possible options; you can of course implement any logic you like.

The calls to `ignore` (always returning `nil`) indicate that our custom hooks have not "processed" the corresponding command-line argument. That is, we only want to effect a state change in the presence of unrecognised command-line arguments, not handle them manually.

#### Option 1

Assume all unrecognised options are files worthy of inhibiting the startup screen for. This option probably corresponds the most to what the default startup procedure is like.

```el
(defun my-inhibit-startup-screen-always ()
  "Startup screen inhibitor for `command-line-functions`.
Inhibits startup screen on the first unrecognised option."
  (ignore (setq inhibit-startup-screen t)))

(add-hook 'command-line-functions #'my-inhibit-startup-screen-always)
```

#### Option 2

Only inhibit startup screen when existing files are passed as arguments.

```el
(defun my-inhibit-startup-screen-file ()
  "Startup screen inhibitor for `command-line-functions`.
Inhibits startup screen on the first unrecognised option which
names an existing file."
  (ignore
   (setq inhibit-startup-screen
         (file-exists-p
          (expand-file-name argi command-line-default-directory)))))

(add-hook 'command-line-functions #'my-inhibit-startup-screen-file)
```

#### Option 3

Only inhibit startup screen when an unrecognised option has a file extension.

```el
(defun my-inhibit-startup-screen-ext ()
  "Startup screen inhibitor for `command-line-functions`.
Inhibits startup screen on the first unrecognised option which
has a file name extension."
  (ignore (setq inhibit-startup-screen (file-name-extension argi))))

(add-hook 'command-line-functions #'my-inhibit-startup-screen-ext)
```

Comment: Very cool! Option 2 is now in my `.emacs`.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I just read the documentation for the customisable variable `initial-buffer-choice` and it relates to this startup procedure; I recommend you have a look.

Comment: None of the above options in the "accepted" solution work for me using GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (2019 Jan) on Mac OS. A solution that works is the one offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744672/unable-to-hide-welcome-screen-in-emacs), where this command is to be added to the init.el file in the ~/.emacs.d directory: (setq inhibit-startup-screen t)